# How to get timeout to redirect to a specific page (using Web.config)

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, web-config

I am trying to get my website to redirect to a specific page on timeout.

I currently have the timeout working which looks like:

```
<sessionState timeout="1">
</sessionState>
```

inside of my config. However, I can't figure out how to get it to redirect to a specific page after the timeout.

I don't know if I can do it within the config folder, or should it be part of the html?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after:
[Redirect Page After Session Time Out in ASP.Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/0c1bb2/redirect-page-after-session-time-out-in-asp-net424/)

I know it is not STRICTLY just web.config, but it is the best answer I could come up with.

Comment: Links to other sites do not make good answers. You should include enough information directly in your answer to sufficient answer the question, giving credit if your answer is based on someone else's work.

Comment: Well, good luck Sophia, I'm going to take a break from this site for a few weeks.  Too much negativity.  (I'm sure this post will generate yet more)

Comment: There is no need to be upset. No one here is attacking you. We have a certain way of doing things that are designed to keep the quality on this site high. Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of useful questions and answers. The link you posted could easily break in the future. It's important to put enough content in your answer to give a working solution, crediting others if you base your answer off their work. That's why link only answers are discouraged. It's also important to take constructive criticism and improve.

Comment: Thanks Trey, unfortunately the site didn't have what I was looking for but appreciate the help :)

Comment: My pleasure, sorry it did not help.